# Code style in android application

Tags: android, coding-style

Is next link refers also to writing android applications or just to operation system - open android project?

https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/opensource/submit-patches/code-style-guide#field_names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this link refer to the coding style for AOSP. Moreover, it's an old page. New page is available [here](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html). Actually, each developer can have his own style for his applications. This page is created to uniform coding styles for those who contribute to AOSP. But you can take this coding style as a reference for your projects.

Comment: Thanks for the new page link.  I had been referring to the old one and they shut it down for public access.